# Why are margins and flexbox gap different in mobile than desktop inspect?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive, margin

I have an issue with this little project:

https://weather-thanos.netlify.app/
https://github.com/thanosoncode/weather-react

When I inspect project for mobile sizes in desktop I can see margins and flexbox gap that disappears when in mobile.

I have media queries of course and even with much less view size than my actual phone is, it looks great in inspect.

Any ideas why that might happen?

https://github.com/thanosoncode/weather-react/blob/main/Screenshot_20211117_133044_com.huawei.browser.jpg

https://github.com/thanosoncode/weather-react/blob/main/local.jpg

Comment: I can't tell you why, but I can tell you that I've had similar issues before. The desktop inspector has limitations. Sometimes you need to inspect the phone browser directly to figure out what's going on. https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/google-chrome-how-to-inspect-websites-on-mobile-devices-804677f863ce

Comment: @BrettDonald Wow. Didn't know about that. Directly inspecting phone helped a lot thanks! That along with your top flexbox post to switch to grid. thanks again